# can't fix video to bounds of screen using geometry reader

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, video-player

i have video and when i rotate my device(in simulator) to landscape left in top and bottom of screen black space remains

this is my code:

```
   GeometryReader { geo in
   ZStack {   
         if self.getIsLandscape(geometry: geo) {
               MKAVideo(player: $player)
               .frame(width: geo.size.width,height: geo.size.height) // <- this is not working
                                    
                                    
          } else {
               MKAVideo(player: $player)
               .scaledToFit()
               .frame(width:  geo.size.width)
                        }
     }
     }
```

[image: this picture]

Comment: This depends on `MKAVideo` internals if it fills provided external `.frame` or not.

Comment: @Asperi in **MKAVideo** when i set videoGravity to **resizeAspectFill** top of my screen get fixed with video but bottom still is empty

Comment: Have you tried to add ignore safe area modifier?

Comment: @RajaKishan yes, but bottom side still is empty